# Roslyn syntax tree transformation - Replacing return type of methods

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to write code transformation using Roslyn that changes return type of interface methods from `T` to `Task<T>` (assuming no void returns). Following is the code I came up with.

**CODE**

```
InterfaceDeclarationSyntax asyncInterface = syncInterface.ReplaceNodes(
                syncInterface.Members.OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>(),
                (a, m) => m.ReplaceNode(
                    m.ReturnType,
                    SF.GenericName(SF.Identifier("Task"), SF.TypeArgumentList(new SeparatedSyntaxList<TypeSyntax>().Add(m.ReturnType)))));
```

**Firstly** is this the right approach?

**Secondly** this messes up the indentation when formatted. How should I fix that?

**Edit**

I was able to solve second problem by preserving Trivia. Here is the updated code (I also migrated it to use rewriter).

**Code**

```
sealed class AsyncMethodRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax m)
    {
        var newReturnType = SF.GenericName(SF.Identifier("Task"), SF.TypeArgumentList(new SeparatedSyntaxList<TypeSyntax>().Add(m.ReturnType.WithoutTrivia())));
        newReturnType = newReturnType.InsertTriviaBefore(newReturnType.GetLeadingTrivia().First(), m.ReturnType.GetLeadingTrivia().AsEnumerable());
        newReturnType = newReturnType.InsertTriviaAfter(newReturnType.GetTrailingTrivia().First(), m.ReturnType.GetTrailingTrivia().AsEnumerable());
        return m.ReplaceNode(m.ReturnType, newReturnType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You choose right approach, but you can simplify your code with `WithReturnType` method for `MethodDeclarationSyntax` and `AddTypeArgumentListArguments` method for `GenericNameSyntax` class
2. Try use `NormalizeWhitespace()` method for format leading and trailing trivias

try this code:

```
syncInterface
  .ReplaceNodes(
      syncInterface.Members.OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>(),
      (a, b) =>
          b.WithReturnType(
              SyntaxFactory.GenericName("Task").AddTypeArgumentListArguments(b.ReturnType)))
  .NormalizeWhitespace();
```